# I have to print the index where the pattern is found. Like if string = "ABCABCDEABCDEA" and pattern = "ABCD", the output will be 4 and 9

Tags: java

This is my code that i have written, it is giving wrong output.I have to print the index where the pattern is found. Like if string = "ABCABCDEABCDEA" and pattern = "ABCD", the output will be 4 and 9

Let me discuss it's approach-What i want is if the ith element of the string is equal to the 0th element of the pattern. then go inside the loop, and check till pattern.length. Else continue.

```
public class Word_check {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str1="ABCDAFGFGFABCDKLHKHABCD";
    String tocheck="ABCD";
    boolean isfound=false;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str1.length();i++) {
        
        if(str1.charAt(i)==tocheck.charAt(count)){
            
            for(int j=i;j<tocheck.length();j++) {
            
                if(str1.charAt(j)==tocheck.charAt(count)) {
                    
                    isfound=true;
                }
                else {
                    isfound=false;
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if(isfound==true) {
                System.out.println(i+1);
            }
            
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        count=0;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: go for indexOf, that should be a lot easier to implement

Comment: [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str1="ABCDAFGFGFABCDKLHKHABCD";
    String tocheck="ABCD";
    int lastIndex = str1.indexOf(tocheck);
    while (lastIndex != -1){
        System.out.println(lastIndex);
        lastIndex = str1.indexOf(tocheck, lastIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

From your example I see that you want to print index + 1 (in java indexes start from 0, hence the program should print 3 and 8). If that is the case, just do `System.out.println(lastIndex + 1);`

Comment: Tried, it goes into the infinite loop, and keep on printing the lastindex, Not working

Comment: Its working, Thanx

Answer (score 1):

As @Stultuske wrote, use indexOf():

```
var index = str1.indexOf("ABCD");
while (index >= 0) {
    System.out.println(index);
    index = str1.indexOf("ABCD", index + 1);
}
```

Comment: Its working, Thanx